# Android wrap_content not working on recyclerview

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I have a very simple RecyclerView that loads data from a Firestore database. There are no issues with the code to get the data but the RecyclerView does not show anything when I set the view holder to wrap_content. However it does load the data when I set it to match_parent. I have tried using

```
firestoreRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true)
```

but it doesnt do anything, the data is just not shown at all when I use wrap_content and using match_parent makes it so that i have to scroll a lot to see a single item.

Here is the code for the RecyclerView row layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="15dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listOfficeName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listOfficeAddress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/listOfficeName" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

There is nothing relevant about the rest, there is functionality only for the RecyclerView that I got from a tutorial in which wrap_content actually worked.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you see both views in the xml editor?

Comment: Do you mean the textviews? I can see them

Comment: why is you constraint layout height match parent, noramlly you would let it wrap content as this is the adapter item view and you want to fit a lot in the same recyclerview, maybe it gets confused by this setting, its worth a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distance of the recyclerview used in ConstraintLayout as a view is disabled because it does not fit the logic of ConstraintLayout. So edit the height value of recyclerview as follows:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp" />
```

**height = 0dp**